# What is the term for, "Don't make it a thing if it isn't a thing"

Tags: terminology

Hoping to find the exact term for situations like the following:

Example: 
An online profile mentions that the person is drama-free. If they were actually drama-free, they would not need to mention it in the first place.

Another example:
You walk into an interview and immediately tell your potential employer that you are not a robot.

Another example: Mentioning that the project details are subject to OPSEC is a violation of OPSEC.

I've heard several phrases that allude to the concept:
"Don't make it a thing if it isn't a thing."
"Keep it self-evident."

It's an oddly-specific type of catch-22 where it's taboo to bring something up in conversation without the other person becoming suspicious as to why you even mentioned it.

Similar concept explained [here (tvtropes - don't explain the joke)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontExplainTheJoke)

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Lofty, [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Comment: Related: [term for being defensive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312744/term-for-being-defensive/312745#312745) (where the expression '... protest too much ...' is suggested).

Comment: The first rule of Fight Club ...

Comment: In fact, it goes without saying that the first rule of Fight Club ...

Comment: You could call it a **suspicious non-sequitur** perhaps.  https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur

Comment: That is sufficiently close to what I'm going for! If anyone else has something more precise, that'd be great - otherwise I'd say this is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

[Procatalepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procatalepsis) (or sometimes "prokatalepsis") is the denial of something before it even comes up; it's applicable to any of those "I know what you're going to say..." denials.

But for subtle accusations by others, you're probably looking at [apophasis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apophasis).

These don't cover the specific case of denying the opposite by negating a word  though, so what you're describing may be a variety of [litotes](http://www.virtualsalt.com/rhetoric.htm#Litotes).